# Kotlin interfaces correlation with Java interfaces

Tags: interface, kotlin

I'm practicing with collections in Kotlin and cannot understand behavior of interfaces. Here is background of my question:

```
public interface List<out E> : Collection<E> {...}
public interface MutableList<E> : List<E>, MutableCollection<E> {...}
```

`List` and `MutableList` are interfaces defined in Kotlin, which is easy to understand. Now if I want to get an instance of a List these methods can be used: `arrayListOf()` or `mutableListOf()`. Both methods use the same `typealias`, which is actually links to the Java implementation of `ArrayList`.

```
public typealias ArrayList<E> = java.util.ArrayList<E>
```

Here a mysterious thing, `MutableList` doesn't have an implementation in Kotlin, so how Kotlin knows that java.util.ArrayList can be assigned to a `MutableList` variable? In other words, how Kotlin and Java interfaces are correlated to each other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interfaces in Kotlin have a one-to-one relationship with Java interfaces. `MutableList` and other collection interfaces are an exception to this; they are handled by the compiler in a special way to support the separation between read-only and writable collection interfaces.

Comment: Are any good resources over the Internet to read about the compiler internals? Especially related to interfaces processing.

Comment: The only resource covering the internals would be the [compiler source code](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin/blob/master/core/descriptors.jvm/src/org/jetbrains/kotlin/platform/JavaToKotlinClassMap.kt).

Comment: thx for the link! I was afraid that the source code is in `C` but hopefully it's not:)

Comment: The Kotlin compiler is a JVM application. Why would its source code be in C?

Comment: Does `IntArray` handled by the compiler internally? It source code looks more like an interface.

Comment: This specific treatment is also described in https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/java-interop.html.